# sqlalchemy class_instrument event doesn't fire

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't figure out how to get the `class_instrument` event to fire. Maybe that's expected, I can't tell for sure from the docs if instrument events are only suppose to fire for custom instrumentation setups.

But the `attribute_instrument` does, so i figured i'd ask.

Docs here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#module-sqlalchemy.orm.instrumentation.

```py
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)


  @listens_for(A, 'class_instrument')
  def on_class_instrument(mapper, cls):
    """"""
    print('class_instrument')
    cls.data.info['cls'] = True


  @listens_for(A, 'attribute_instrument')
  def on_attribute_instrument(cls, key, inst):
    """"""
    print('attribute_instrument', cls)
    cls.data.info['attr'] = True


  a = A()
  assert A.data.info['attr']
  # Succeeds above, but fails here
  assert A.data.info['cls']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Declarative the class is instrumented during construction, so your event handler is bound too late. Mappers on the other hand are configured lazily first time they are needed, so the attributes are instrumented when you first use `A`.

Looking at the documentation you should bind your listeners to your `Base` class. Instrumentation event listeners default to `propagate=True`, so you'll receive instrumentation events for subclasses of `Base`:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  @listens_for(Base, 'class_instrument')
  def on_class_instrument(cls):
    """"""
    print('class_instrument')
    cls.data.info['cls'] = True

  @listens_for(Base, 'attribute_instrument')
  def on_attribute_instrument(cls, key, inst):
    """"""
    print('attribute_instrument', cls)
    cls.data.info['attr'] = True

  class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)    

  a = A()
  assert A.data.info['attr']
  # Succeeds
  assert A.data.info['cls']
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Never thought about adding it before. Thank you!